# Dependent and bound filters in a pivot table

Tags: sql, excel, pivot, pivot-table

In Sheet1 I have raw data that looks something like this:

```
event_name | country | event_datetime | event_day | vertical | some_metric
fun day 2018 | uk | 1/1/2018 22:00 | 1/1/2018 | something | 100
fun day 2018 | uk | 1/1/2018 23:00 | 1/1/2018 | something | 200
fun day 2018 | uk | 2/1/2018 00:00 | 2/1/2018 | something | 300
fun day 2017 | uk | 1/1/2017 22:00 | 1/1/2017 | something | 400
fun day 2017 | uk | 1/1/2017 23:00 | 1/1/2017 | something | 500
fun day 2017 | uk | 2/1/2017 00:00 | 2/1/2017 | something | 600
```

event_datetime is rounded to the nearest hour. events can run across multiple days.

In Sheet2 I create a pivot table using all this data. The filters are event_name, country, event_datetime; the first column is vertical and the values is sum(some_metric).

***Is there a way of making the dates that show up dependent on the event_name selected?*** e.g. if I select fun day 2018, I just want the dates that correspond to this event to show up in the event_datetime filter dropdown (i.e. for fun day 2018 only 1/1/2018 and 2/1/2018 with all the corresponding times should come up). At the moment, all the dates show up for any event.

***Is there a way to "group" the event_datetime's so that if an event is say 36 hours, I can select 24 hours / 30 hour views for that event?*** e.g. for fun day 2018 the 24 hour view would be anything with date 1/1/2018, 30 hours would be anything with date 1/1/2018 and the first 6 hours of 2/1/2018.

I am using Microsoft Excel on Mac Version 16.14.1. If there is a structure change I can make in the raw data itself which would enable 1/2 above to be simpler in the pivot please let me know and I can edit the SQL generating this data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is there a way of making the dates that show up [in the filter dropdown] dependent on the event_name selected?** No. But try using a Slicer...they can give you the kind of effect you're after, where things that are 'selectable' show up at the top of the Slicer. You may need to play around with the settings.

**Is there a way to "group" the event_datetime [by time elapsed]?** Yes, but it will require you to add another column to your data that shows time elapsed, which will then let you set a Less Than filter on that field. But because this only works for rowfields, you'll need to use a workaround using a second hidden PivotTable and a slicer to get it to work. I have an answer somewhere on this site that I'll try to find and link to later today.

Given your requirements, I think you should just use a simple Table (and not a PivotTable) to filter and display this data. Hopefully the mac version you have allows you to put slicers on a Table, like the most recent versions of Excel do.

You can handle the time grouping requirement by adding a couple of new columns and a couple of parameter cells like below:

[image]

The orange cells have been assigned the named ranges of DayOfInterest and HoursWithin respectively

Time Elapsed: `=[@[ event_datetime ]]-DayOfInterest`

Time Groupings: `=AND([@[Time Elapsed]]>0,[@[Time Elapsed]]<HoursWitthin/24)`

This lets you set the parameter in the Hours Within to anything you want (24, 36, 48) and this then causes the Time Groupings formula to show True/False, which you can then filter on.

With a bit of VBA you can also make it more dynamic...i.e. you can have the filter apply automatically whenever someone changes the orange Input cells. You just need to add this VBA to the Sheet Module corresponding to the sheet this is in.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, [DayOfInterest]) Is Nothing _
Or Not Intersect(Target, [HoursWithin]) Is Nothing Then
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Time_Groupings")
        .ClearAllFilters
        On Error Resume Next
        .SlicerItems("TRUE").Selected = True
        .SlicerItems("FALSE").Selected = False
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I generate the raw data so if I can make a change to my raw data (just need to adjust the SQL) then I can do. An example of link of how to do the above (especially #2) would be great as I did not consider using a normal table which seems like a good idea.

Comment: Question: Does your project support VBA?

Comment: Slicers worked great (I ended up adjusting the query a bit to get the additional slicers instead of grouping through slicers). :

Comment: Cool. See my amended answer re your second requirement. Please mark the question as helpful and/or solved if this helps.